# How to find a matrix that produced a symmetric matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition, ellipsoids

$$M=\begin{bmatrix} m_{00} & m_{01} & m_{02}\\ m_{10} & m_{11} & m_{12} \\ m_{20} & m_{21}& m_{22} \end{bmatrix} $$

$$ M^{T}M =  \begin{bmatrix} a & d & e\\ d & b & f \\ e & f& c \end{bmatrix} $$

$$ M.\begin{bmatrix} x_0 \\ y_0 \\z_0 \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ y_1 \\z_1 \end{bmatrix}$$

so it will be:

$$ a = m_{20}^{2} + m_{10}^{2} + m_{00}^{2} $$
$$ b = m_{21}^{2} + m_{11}^{2} + m_{01}^{2} $$
$$ c = m_{22}^{2} + m_{12}^{2} + m_{02}^{2} $$
$$ d = m_{20}.m_{21} + m_{10}.m_{11} + m_{00}.m_{01} $$
$$ e = m_{20}.m_{22 }+ m_{10}.m_{12} + m_{00}.m_{02} $$
$$ f = m_{21}.m_{22} + m_{11}.m_{12}  + m_{01}.m_{02} $$
$$ x_1 = m_{02}.z_0 + m_{01}.y_0 + m_{00}.x_0 $$
$$ y_1 = m_{12}.z_0 + m_{11}.y_0 + m_{10}.x_0 $$
$$ z_1 = m_{22}.z_0 + m_{21}.y_0 + m_{20}.x_0 $$

Question: what is a direct solution to find $\mathbf{m_{00}, m_{01}, m_{22}}$ ?

**a,b,c,d,e,f** as well $\mathbf{x_0,y_0,z_0,x_1,y_1,z_1}$ are known.

I tried with iteration method. here is the python code:

```
# select an initial m. first one has better results
m = np.array([[ 3.0 , 0.0 , 0.0 ],
              [ 0.0 , 3.0 , 0.0 ],
              [ 0.0 , 0.0 , 3.0 ]] )
# m = np.array([[ math.sqrt(a) , 0            , 0            ] ,
#               [ 0            , math.sqrt(b) , 0            ] ,
#               [ 0            , 0            , math.sqrt(c) ] ])
trace = [[]]
m1 = m.copy()
for i in range(1000):
    # Newton's method for m00,m11,m22
    # m1[0,0] = m[0,0] - (m[2,0]**2 + m[1,0]**2 + m[0,0]**2 - a) / (2*m[0,0])
    # m1[1,1] = m[1,1] - (m[2,1]**2 + m[1,1]**2 + m[0,1]**2 - b) / (2*m[1,1])
    # m1[2,2] = m[2,2] - (m[2,2]**2 + m[1,2]**2 + m[0,2]**2 - c) / (2*m[2,2])
    # direct method for m00,m11,m22
    m1[0,0] = math.sqrt( abs( a - m[2,0]**2 - m[1,0]**2 ) )
    m1[1,1] = math.sqrt( abs( b - m[2,1]**2 - m[0,1]**2 ) )
    m1[2,2] = math.sqrt( abs( c - m[1,2]**2 - m[0,2]**2 ) )

    m1[0,1] = (d - (m[2,0]*m[2,1] + m[1,0]*m[1,1])) / m[0,0]
    m1[0,2] = (x1 - (m[0,1]*y0 + m[0,0]*x0)) / z0

    m1[1,0] = ( m[2,0]*( y1 - (m[1,2]*z0 + m[1,1]*y0) ) ) / ( z1 - m[2,2]*z0 - m[2,1]*y0 )
    m1[1,2] = (y1 - (m[1,1]*y0 + m[1,0]*x0)) / z0

    m1[2,0] = (e - (m[1,0]*m[1,2] + m[0,0]*m[0,2])) / m[2,2]
    m1[2,1] = (f - (m[1,1]*m[1,2] + m[0,1]*m[0,2])) / m[2,2]

    m = 0.01 * m1 + 0.99*m
    trace.append( m.reshape(-1).tolist() )
```

for a supposed Matrix:
$$ M =  \begin{bmatrix} 1.1 & -0.1 & 0.2\\ 0.3 & 1.2 & -0.1 \\ 0.1 & -0.3 & 0.9 \end{bmatrix} $$

the result is:
$$ M =  \begin{bmatrix} 1.14312 & 0.209234 & 0.2\\ 0.00182697 & 1.16508 & -0.1 \\ 0.0572922 & -0.372589 & 0.9 \end{bmatrix} $$

[here you can see trace of results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYe3E.png)

Comment: 1) Do you agree that your question can/should be reformulated into: being given a matrix $A$, find $M$ such that $M^TM=A$ ? 2) What is the point of giving this program : it looks to work, then "what else ?"

Comment: yes, actually it is a decomposition of ellipsoid but not to limited to eigensystem. it a general decomposition includes any possible strained ellipsoid.

Comment: You haven't answered my second question : a) is your iterative program working in all situations b) What do you want from us ? Find a non iterative solution ?

Comment: as you can see, only The third column is true. other are not!

Comment: So, why don't you say it, with words as you have done right now  instead for us to have to look at the figures. Besides, this is only an example : if you take other examples, is the  "third column" always the good one ?

Comment: If such is the case, this is encouraging: your Newton's method "works already at one third" : there must be algebraic errors in the computation of the gradient.

Comment: yes, the problem is the same for any sample matrix. it seems that some results(for example m20 and m10) have deviation from destination that make other results to be diverted in the wrong direction. Actually I think there must be an algebraic solution. Because they are polynomial equations. 9 equation for 9 variable!

Answer (score 1):

Here are two different approaches 1) and 2).

- 1. Let $A$ be a real symmetric matrix. We are looking for a square matrix $M$ of the same size as $A$ with real entries such that

$$M^TM=A$$

A necessary condition is that symmetric matrix $A$ must have $\ge 0$ eigenvalues (see explanation below).

In this case, we can diagonalize $A$ under the form

$$A=Q^T\Lambda Q\tag{1}$$

where $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix with $\lambda_k \ge 0$ entries. Therefore $\Lambda = \Delta^T\Delta$ where $\Delta$ is a diagonal matrix with (diagonal) entries $\sqrt{\lambda_k}$

Therefore (1) can be written

$$A=(\Delta Q)^T(\Delta Q)$$

meaning that $M=\Delta Q$ is a solution.

More generaly, for any orthogonal matrix $\Omega$,

$$M=\Omega\Delta Q$$

is a solution.

See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2858336/305862 for a similar answer to a different question adressing rectangular matrices with rank condition.

---

**Explanation** about the positivity of eigenvalues :

Quadratic form $X^T(M^TM)X=(MX)^T(MX)=\|MX\|^2 \ge 0$

is (indeed!) semi-definite positive.

---

- 2. A completely different approach is to use [Cholesky decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition) $A=C^TC$ (or in case one or more of the eigenvalues is $0$, the *incomplete* Cholesky factorization) with $C$ an *upper triangular* matrix.

Comment: More exactly the square roots of the eigenvalues. Besides, I have given a second track (Cholesky factorisation) that I hadn't in mind at first.

Comment: Dear Jean many thanks for the answer. the answer is true when **A** be a rotated scaled ellipsoid. then the direction of rotation can be found from eigen vectors and the eigen values show the scaling.
actually I am looking for how big **strained** a desired Ellipsoid(A) in each of directions x,y and z. so the cholesky decomposition can not decompose this informations.
it's why I there is a sample vector x0, y0 , z0 that maped to x1,y1,z1.
all eigen values are >0 and near 1

Comment: If all the eignevalues are around $0$ this is not good news: your ellipsoid is close to a sphere : therefore you are likely to encounter instability in applying numerical methods.

Comment: actually matrix $$M^TM=A$$ is produced by least squares from cloud points of vectors. and x1, y1,z1 is a sample poit that mapped from x0,y0,z0 , to help find the Matrix **M**.